# wxformbuilder doesn't add validators on textctrl to code

Tags: wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I'm trying to make some app using wxwidgets. I created a bit of GUI using wxformbuilder and now I want one of my textctrl to use numeric validator. I set it up in wxformbuilder like this:

[image: validator settings in wxformbuilder]

So I made `validator_type` `wxTextValidator`, checked `validator_style`: `wxFILTER_NUMERIC` and unchecked `wxFILTER_NONE`. And set `validator_data_type` to `wxString`.

But it seems that there's no code related to validators in generated files.
Here's all code that works with that textctrl:

```
m_textCtrl5 = new wxTextCtrl( m_panel9, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_RIGHT );
fgSizer9->Add( m_textCtrl5, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );
```

I tried to make it earlier and I had the same problem. I generated inherited class and made it work by simply writing that validator code myself but I don't want to do the same thing now.

Am I doing something wrong or is this thing just not working?

Comment: why not add validator by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a numeric validator, you also need to assign a string variable to hold the contents being validated.  In wxFormbuilder you just need to fill in the "validator_variable" area like so:

[image]